# Area of a parallelogram with three points in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$: $(a,b, 0); (a, 0, b); (0, a, b)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been requested to calculate the area of the parallelogram with three adjacent vertices: $(a,b, 0); (a, 0, b); (0, a, b).

First, I have made this diagram:

[image: Parallelogram in 3D]

Then I proceed to calculate the two vectors from $Q$ to $P$, and from $Q$ to $R$:

$\vec{QP}=(-a, a-b, b)$

$\vec{QR}=(0, -b, b)$

And the area calculation:

$$
Area=\begin{vmatrix}
  i & j & k \\
  -a & a-b & b \\
  0 & -b & b
 \end{vmatrix}=\|(b(a-b)+b^{2})i+(ab)j-(ab)k\|
$$

which is equals to:

$$
=\sqrt{(b(a-b)+b^{2})^{2}+(ab)^{2}+(-(ab))^{2}}\ \text{square units}
$$

Is this procedure correct? Is the diagram a valid representation for those vertices?

Comment: Yes, but can simplify it further

Comment: @BobRoberts, How I can proceed to make that simplification?

Comment: Looks good to me - notice that you can simplify what's inside your square root considerably

Comment: $b(a-b) + b^2 = ba$ which gives you a final answer of $\sqrt 3 ab$

Comment: for instance: $(b(a-b)+b^2)^2 = (ba-b^2+b^2)^2 = (ba)^2 = (ab)^2 = (-(ab))^2$

Comment: How I can generalize the graphical representation?

Answer (score 0):

your cross product is not quite right. The plane of the three points is $$ x + y + z = a + b. $$ A normal to the plane is a multiple of $(1,1,1).$ You have a multiple of $(1,1,-1)$